# Custom resource type google cloud healthcare api fhir

Tags: google-cloud-healthcare, google-healthcare-api

We have developed a custom FHIR resource type called VacancyRequest to be used for interoperability between workforce management systems. Im trying to understand if the google cloud healthcase api FHIR supports custom resource types or only resources supported by the fhir standard itself such as Patient, Encounter etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Healthcare does not support custom FHIR resource types.

The workaround is to use the Basic resource (an empty resource defined by the FHIR spec) with extensions to represent all of the fields in your resource, typically with some sort of "type" field to indicate that an instance is a VacancyRequest in case there are multiple uses of Basic in the application.